# Face tagging for very large photo library

Tags: windows, linux, file-management, photography

Is there software that would allow me to tag faces in a library of over 1 million photos?

I have used Picasa for smaller numbers of photos, and I like how it groups faces together, so that you can tag all instances of a face in one go.

My objective is, once all the tagging is done, to be able to quickly find all photos of a person. Essentially the face tagging feature in Picasa, but scaling to thousands of faces and over 1 million photos.

It can work on any version of Windows or Linux. I would need something very inexpensive to try it out, but if it works well then I may have a budget of a few hundred dollars.

Comment: What are your system specs, maybe adding RAM or faster hard drive (SSD) will make more picture viable in picasa.  Picasa uses a database and databases love RAM and CPU to a lesser degree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open-source image organiser with face recognition (alternative to Picasa) with OSX/Linux support](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26623/open-source-image-organiser-with-face-recognition-alternative-to-picasa-with-o)

Comment: @Suncatcher Yes, that looks like good info, thanks.